# converting from BigInt to BitArray

Tags: rust, binary, bitset, bigint

what would be best way to convert object using rust from bigint (BigInt) to bits (BitArray<217>) also in reverse (example below)

using binary to decimal calculator I verified by hand that bigint and bits equate

```
let bigint = BigInt::parse_bytes("141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197".as_ref(), 10);

to 

let bits = BitArray::new( [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]);
```

crates ref.

for BigInt: https://crates.io/crates/num-bigint (num-bigint = "0.4.3")

for BitArray: https://crates.io/crates/bitarray (bitarray = "0.10.0")

Comment: You can't; `BitArray`'s size is known at compile time, but `BigInt`'s size is only known at runtime. Unless you want to hard-code that this number is 217 bits long?

Comment: Further, `BigInt` is signed, but `BitArray` is unsigned, at least the version you show here.

Comment: Third, your statement that it equals to said `BitArray` is incorrect. It actually equals to `BitArray::new([1, 88, 81, 147, 230, 162, 120, 203, 210, 232, 153, 239, 115, 92, 222, 74, 147, 18, 216, 202, 55, 207, 181, 126, 72, 92, 248, 109])`.

Comment: @Finomnis https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html shows them equal 

also closest I got to binary notation is this let s = format!("{bigint:b}") but I want array [u8, 217] yes and so number of bits is 217

also one can ignore Sign in this syntax bigint.unwrap().to_bytes_be().1

in the nutshell how to make rust do same thing as that calculator in that link

 let s = format!("{bigint:b}" produces exactly the binary string (bits object) except its in the String format (and not array what is desired)

217 len will be fixed (in my situation) thanks for all help!

Comment: `[u8, 217]` is a lot more than 217 bits. Are you sure?

Comment: compiler itself tips (in the IDE):  let bits: BitArray<217> =  BitArray::new( bytes: [...])

Comment: Well, yes, but you are constructing the bitarray incorrect, you are not supposed to give it only ones and zeros

Comment: its really True False (1, 0) array I mean what I want it to be represented as binary 0 and 1's

Comment: Yes, I understand that :) but that's not how the `bitarray` crate works. I think this is the wrong crate for you. What you are talking about is `Vec<bool>`, and you don't need any library for it. `bitarray` is a **packed** bit array, meaning 8 bits per value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of misconceptions:

- You can't convert a size known at runtime (`BigInt`) to a size known at compile time (`BitArray`)
- `BigInt` is signed, but at no point during your conversion you consider signedness. You probably want to use [`BigUint`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/latest/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html) instead if you want to ignore signedness.
- Your `BitArray` for comparison only consists of `1` and `0` values. `bitarray::BitArray`, however, is meant as bytes, meaning, each value is 8 bits, valued from `0` to `255`. If you convert it, the value is actually `BitArray::new([1, 88, 81, 147, 230, 162, 120, 203, 210, 232, 153, 239, 115, 92, 222, 74, 147, 18, 216, 202, 55, 207, 181, 126, 72, 92, 248, 109])` and `28` long.
- `bitarray::BitArray` does not seem to be able to iterate over it bitwise, so I don't know how useful this library is for you. The fact that it forces compile time size is also not compatible with your usecase. You should probably choose a different library. The entire concept of a "bit array" is probably not what you want, you probably want a "bit vector" instead with a runtime size.

That said, `bitarray` consists of **packed bits**, meaning 8 bits per value (or more). If you want a pure `Vec<bool>`, you don't need any of this, you can directly convert it to that:

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn main() {
    let bigint = BigUint::parse_bytes(
        "141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197".as_ref(),
        10,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let bits = bigint
        .to_bytes_be()
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|val| {
            [
                (val >> 7) & 1,
                (val >> 6) & 1,
                (val >> 5) & 1,
                (val >> 4) & 1,
                (val >> 3) & 1,
                (val >> 2) & 1,
                (val >> 1) & 1,
                (val >> 0) & 1,
            ]
            .into_iter()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", bits);
}
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Not that the value you give seems to be little-endian, while this one is big-endian.

---

Here is an even shorter version, utilizing the crate [`bitvec`](https://docs.rs/bitvec):

```rust
use bitvec::{order::Msb0, vec::BitVec};
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn main() {
    let bigint = BigUint::parse_bytes(
        "141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197".as_ref(),
        10,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let bits: BitVec<_, Msb0> = BitVec::from_vec(bigint.to_bytes_be());
    println!("{}", bits);
}
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Or, if you prefer little endian:

```rust
use bitvec::{order::Lsb0, vec::BitVec};
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn main() {
    let bigint = BigUint::parse_bytes(
        "141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197".as_ref(),
        10,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let bits: BitVec<_, Lsb0> = BitVec::from_vec(bigint.to_bytes_le());
    println!("{}", bits);
}
```

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note that while `bits` is packed, you can still iterate over it bitwise. If you want to convert it to a `u8` vector, do:

```rust
let bits_u8: Vec<u8> = bits.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect();
```

Comment: thanks much I will try that, code will later iterate thru this array checking for true false no binary operations needed just booleans in the array obtained from a big decimal (generated randomly)

Comment: Turns out your information is wrong, converting `141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197` to binary is `1010110000101000110010011111001101010001001111000110010111101001011101000100110011110111101110011010111001101111001001010100100110001001011011000110010100011011111001111101101010111111001001000010111001111100001101101`, which is also what I get in my last code example.

Comment: but I also get that using online calculator https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html

141644482300309102636663083870634002744809361056209271964506585197 

->

1010110000101000110010011111001101010001001111000110010111101001011101000100110011110111101110011010111001101111001001010100100110001001011011000110010100011011111001111101101010111111001001000010111001111100001101101

Comment: maybe the calculator is wrong, .. thanks so much for last reply with the 0,1 array, down the stream library expects such not True False I could rewire for booleans but this saves time

Comment: Note that you are wasting a lot of space if you use `u8` to represent a single bit, though.

Comment: @zkbitcoin.com The number you just posted is correct, but is not the same number as you posted at the beginning.

Comment: changing 

let bits = bigint
        .to_bytes_le()
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|val| {
            let val = [
                (val >> 0) & 1,
                (val >> 1) & 1,
                (val >> 2) & 1,
                (val >> 3) & 1,
                (val >> 4) & 1,
                (val >> 5) & 1,
                (val >> 6) & 1,
                (val >> 7) & 1,
            ];

close equates minus last 7 padded 0 bytes

only doing this with u8 because down the stream lib is wired for u8 and this format

Comment: Well then you have little endian, indeed. If that's what you want ... The zeros are ok and mean nothing at little endian.

Comment: and now with this (bits.resize(217, 0);) arrays matched perfectly, this is part of cryptographic academia project but for mission critical definitely u8 is costly..

thank you so so much again, this really solves it, I guess moderator can close this query

Comment: @zkbitcoin.com Added a better solution using the excellent `bitvec` library.